# Bootstrap/CSS : How to add separate circle radius in a circle button in bootstrap when its active

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys i have a question about doing circle in css and bootstrap.
i have a bootstrap button with border-radius is equal to 50%.
my goal here is to make a separate border radius when its active
[image: Example]

My first approach is manipulating the outline, i have some improvement but 
i can't make my outline circle [image: example2], so my next question is it possible to make outline circle? thanks guys

Comment: if you did the code please provide fiddle

Comment: use a pseudo element.

Comment: thanks sir chirag for the reply, but i just manipulate few codes i just add 
.btn-primary {
   border-radius:50%;
}

.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active {
   outline: #00FF00 dotted thick;
}

Comment: can u provide some codes and explanation sir? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an absolutely positioned pseudo element that goes outside of the button.

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: purple;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
}
button, button:after {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
button.active:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1em; left: -1em; right: -1em; bottom: -1em;
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, black, white);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: transform .25s;
}
```

```html
<button class="active">button</button>

<button>button</button>
```

Comment: hi michael do you know how to add rotate transform with transition in the :after psuedo element when its active? i tried but seems not working thanks